# How to add multiple dropdown with checkboxes in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My HTML code is:

```
 <div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
      <span class="anchor">Select Months</span>
      <ul class="items">
        <li><input type="checkbox" />Apr </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />May</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />June </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />July </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />Aug </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />Sep </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />Oct</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />Nov</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />Dec</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />Jan</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />Feb</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />Mar</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="list2" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
      <span class="anchor">Select Quarter</span>
      <ul class="items">
        <li><input type="checkbox" />Quarter 1</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />Quarter 2</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />Quarter 3</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />Quarter 4 </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="list3" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
      <span class="anchor">Select Monthly/Yearly</span>
      <ul class="items">
        <li><input type="checkbox" />6 Months </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />Year</li>
      
      </ul>
    </div>
```

My CSS code is:

```
.dropdown-check-list {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-check-list .anchor {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 50px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 20%;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor:active:after {
  right: 8px;
  top: 21%;
}

.dropdown-check-list ul.items {
  padding: 2px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.dropdown-check-list ul.items li {
  list-style: none;
}

.dropdown-check-list.visible .anchor {
  color: #0094ff;
}

.dropdown-check-list.visible .items {
  display: block;
}
```

My Javascript code is:

```
var checkList = document.getElementById('list1');
    checkList.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function(evt) {
      if (checkList.classList.contains('visible'))
        checkList.classList.remove('visible');
      else
        checkList.classList.add('visible');
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    var checkList = document.getElementById('list2');
    checkList.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function(evt) {
      if (checkList.classList.contains('visible'))
        checkList.classList.remove('visible');
      else
        checkList.classList.add('visible');
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    var checkList = document.getElementById('list3');
    checkList.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function(evt) {
      if (checkList.classList.contains('visible'))
        checkList.classList.remove('visible');
      else
        checkList.classList.add('visible');
    }
</script>
```

I tried running this code, but by clicking the first and second dropdown only the 3rd dropdown works, the first and second dropdown are not working, so which means that by clicking the first dropdown the 3 dropdown expands and same happens with second.
If someone could please help me out,
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are using the same variable "var checkList" for all three elements "list1", "list2" and "list3". This way when the execution phases reaches this line " var checkList = document.getElementById('list3');" it no longer has a reference to the "list1" and "list2" elements. You can solve this by using three separate variables. for example:

```
var checkList = document.getElementById('list1');
    checkList.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function(evt) {
      if (checkList.classList.contains('visible'))
        checkList.classList.remove('visible');
      else
        checkList.classList.add('visible');
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    var checkList2 = document.getElementById('list2');
    checkList2.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function(evt) {
      if (checkList.classList.contains('visible'))
        checkList.classList.remove('visible');
      else
        checkList.classList.add('visible');
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    var checkList3 = document.getElementById('list3');
    checkList3.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function(evt) {
      if (checkList.classList.contains('visible'))
        checkList.classList.remove('visible');
      else
        checkList.classList.add('visible');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: No problem. Also you don't need three separate script tags for this only one is sufficient.

Answer (score -2):

Many possibilities:

1. change the `var checkList` different for each.
2. This code will drag you in trouble, better to optimize this.
3. If you want to use more easy solution, switch to JQuery, this might be helpful: https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function